# unicode emojis in color with delphi tokyo 10.2

Tags: unicode, colors, emoji, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using delphi 10.2 tokyo with dbmemo control and I would like to know if is even possible show the emojis in color just like in any html webpage like this:

☹

it could be pretty nice

because using tahoma font in the memo show in gray, which is boring hehe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a TEdit show color emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447701/can-a-tedit-show-color-emoji)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the font you are using and also what modifiers you use.
Take these two Unicode characters  and  which when displayed next to each other gives