# Can a TEdit show color emoji?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

I'd like to see emojis in color in a `TEdit` or `TMemo` control using VCL and Delphi 10+.

Can it be done?

Text entered:

```
‍‍‍‍
```

What I see:

[image]

What I'd like to see:

[image]

Comment: Regular Windows controls do not support [Color Fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directwrite/color-fonts).

Comment: Thanks, Brian.   Are there non-regular Windows controls that do?

Comment: The Firemonkey / FMX Edit and Memo do. Tested on Windows 10 with Delphi 10.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unicode emojis in color with delphi tokyo 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947453/unicode-emojis-in-color-with-delphi-tokyo-10-2)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question made me curious, so tried and here is the result:

**Drawing colored fonts in general**

Apparently FMX supports this out of the box in later versions, but not in Seattle, which I happen to have. I don't know if the VCL also supports it out of the box in your version, but if not, you can achieve using Direct2D. The trick is to draw text using the `D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_COLOR_FONT` option.

In Seattle (10), this constant is not defined, and - unfortunately - not used in the default TCanvas-compatible functions. But you can call `DrawText` or one of the other functions yourself and specify the option.

The general structure is based on [this Embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_the_Direct2D_Canvas#Using_Direct2D_canvas_alongside_GDI_canvas). The rest is peeked from TDirect2DCanvas, combined with the [DrawText documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawtext(constwchar_uint32_idwritetextformat_constd2d1_rect_f__id2d1brush_d2d1_draw_text_options_dwrite_measuring_mode)).

```
uses Vcl.Direct2D, Winapi.D2D1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  str: string = 'xyz‍‍‍‍';
  D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_COLOR_FONT = 4;
var
  c: TDirect2DCanvas;
  r: D2D_RECT_F;
begin
  c := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Canvas.Handle, Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
  c.BeginDraw;
  try

    r.left := 0;
    r.top := 0;
    r.right := 100;
    r.bottom := 50;

    // Brush determines the font color.
    c.Brush.Color := clBlack;

    c.RenderTarget.DrawText(
      PWideChar(str), Length(Str), c.Font.Handle, r, c.Brush.Handle,
      D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_COLOR_FONT);
  finally
    c.EndDraw;
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This little piece of code works in a fairly ugly way (in terms of positioning the text), but you can also peek in TDirect2DCanvas, and copy the implementation of one of its text methods to create a function for outputting text in a specific way that you want. And after that it should be fairly easy to apply this to your own TGraphicControl or TCustomControl descendant to create an emoji-supporting label.

**Doing that in TEdit**

To manage this in TEdit is harder, since drawing the text (and the emoji) is handled by the control itself. It should be possible to create a TEdit descendant and/or hook into its WM_PAINT message and paint over the text using this same trick, but I'm not sure how well that would work.

I gave that a quick shot, but it doesn't really work well perfectly, especially when editing. So I've made this descendant of TEdit. When focused, it draws the text in a normal way, and the colored emoji will be black and white, and split into two characters (the emoji and the color combination character). When the edit loses its focus, the custom paint code takes over, which works well in that scenario. Maybe you can attempt to polish it to make it work while editing as well, but then you have to take scrolling, positioning the caret and other stuff into account. For a TMemo descendant that would be even harder. I hope you're happy with just colored display for now. :-)

```
type
  TMyEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

uses Vcl.Direct2D, Winapi.D2D1;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_COLOR_FONT = 4;

constructor TMyEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

procedure TMyEdit.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
var
  c: TDirect2DCanvas;
  r: D2D_RECT_F;
begin
  // Default drawing when focused. Otherwise do the custom draw.
  if Focused then
  begin
    Inherited;
    Exit;
  end;

  c := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(dc, ClientRect);
  c.BeginDraw;
  try

    r.left := ClientRect.Left;
    r.top := ClientRect.Top;
    r.right := ClientRect.Right;
    r.bottom := ClientRect.Bottom;

    // Basic font properties
    c.Font.Assign(Font);
    // Brush determines the font color.
    c.Brush.Color := Font.Color;

    c.RenderTarget.DrawText(
      PWideChar(Text), Length(Text), c.Font.Handle, r, c.Brush.Handle,
      D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_COLOR_FONT);
  finally
    c.EndDraw;
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Added my attempt to a TEdit implementation, although I admit it has some shortcomings.

Comment: I tried it and it works as advertised.  I wanted to see the color when it is focused, so I removed the IF.  But it still draws in B&W when focused.